# Is it possible to create a generic site.xml in a enterprise pom that is inherited by all projects?

Tags: java, maven, maven-site-plugin

I have my parent pom for my organization:

```
<project
   <groupId>org.myorg</groupId>
   <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
   <packaging>pom</packaging>
   <version>6-SNAPSHOT</version>
...
</project>
```

And in that same project is a site.xml:

```
<project>

   <skin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.skins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-fluido-skin</artifactId>
      <version>1.5</version>
   </skin>

   <custom>
      <fluidoSkin>
         <sideBarEnabled>true</sideBarEnabled>
      </fluidoSkin>
   </custom>

   <body>
      <menu ref="reports" />
   </body>
</project>
```

If I run `mvn clean site` I get the fluido theme.

Now, in an actual project somewhere else in the org, it inherits from our enterprise pom, but is not part of a module build for it:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.myorg</groupId>
    <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
    <version>6-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

...
<artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
...
</project>
```

but when I run an `mvn clean site` under `my-project` I get the normal theme, not the fluido theme. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. This used to work, but the default beahavior changed:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/attach-descriptor-mojo.html

> This default execution has been removed from the built-in lifecycle of Maven 3.x for pom-projects. Users that actually use those projects to provide a common site descriptor for sub modules will need to explicitly define this goal execution to restore the intended behavior.

To Fix:

```
  <build>
     <plugins>
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.5.1</version>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
           <attach>true</attach>
        </configuration>
     </plugin>
   </plugins>
 </build>
```

## EDIT

While this make the theme inherit, now the left sidebar is always blank! See my followup question here: [maven-site-plugin: <body> tag is not being inherited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37583106/maven-site-plugin-body-tag-is-not-being-inherited)