# maven-site-plugin: <body> tag is not being inherited

Tags: java, maven, maven-site-plugin

If I do an `mvn site:effective-site` on my parent I get this:

```
<project>
  <bannerLeft>
    <name>xxx :: Open Source Parent POM</name>
  </bannerLeft>
  <publishDate />
  <version />
  <skin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.skins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-fluido-skin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
  </skin>
  <body>
    <menu ref="parent" />
    <menu ref="reports" />
  </body>
</project>
```

However, if I do it on a child project I get this:

```
<project>
  <bannerLeft>
    <name>xxx :: Parent</name>
  </bannerLeft>
  <publishDate />
  <version />
  <skin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.skins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-fluido-skin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
  </skin>
  <body />
</project>
```

Here's my site_en.xml thats in the same project as the parent pom

```
<project>
   <body>
      <menu ref="parent" />
      <menu ref="modules" />
      <menu ref="reports" />
   </body>
   <skin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.skins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-fluido-skin</artifactId>
      <version>1.5</version>
   </skin>
</project>
```

Here's my pom structure for that project

```
<project>
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <groupId>org.myorg</groupId>
   <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
   <packaging>pom</packaging>
   <version>6-SNAPSHOT</version>
...

  <build>
     <plugins>
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.5.1</version>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
           <attach>true</attach>
        </configuration>
     </plugin>
   </plugins>
 </build>
```

Here's the subproject pom that's not inheriting the body:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.myorg</groupId>
    <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
    <version>6-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

...
  <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
...
</project>
```

What gives? Surely I'm not the only one that needs a site template for their whole enterprise!

Comment: Use an more uptodate version of [maven-site-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/) 3.5.1?

Comment: I tried that of course :/ but the crazy thing is, I changed "Something" and it started working

Comment: between switching maven versions, nuking my repo, upgrading/downgrading plugins, it's working now. literally have no idea what I did to make it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<body>
    <menu ref="parent" inherit="bottom"/>
    <menu ref="reports" inherit="bottom"/>
    <menu ref="modules" inherit="bottom"/>
</body>
```

This helped, if set in parent pom's site.xml. Explicit inheritance settings are apparently required, at least in site plugin v.3.7.